# How to add a Hint in spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

XML code of spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions       
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" />`
```

.kotlin:

```
val myStrings = arrayOf("One", "Two" , "Three", "Four")
mySpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myStrings)
mySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("not implemented") 
        //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        TODO("not implemented") 
        //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}}
```

Equal to the "hint" option in Edittext, I need a default text in a Spinner.

Comment: There is no option for hint in `Spinner` . You can make your first element as hint like "Select" or whatever you need . Other option that you need to customized the `Spinner` .

Comment: have you considered using `android:prompt`?

Answer (score 12):

There is not any default way to display hint in spinner.
For this you need to add one item manually in the array like below.

```
val myStrings = arrayOf("Select","One", "Two" , "Three", "Four")
```

Now, 
 Define custom Adapter for the Spinner and disable the first item like below.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        // Disable the first item from Spinner
        // First item will be use for hint
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can change the color like below

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
    if (position == 0) {
        // Set the hint text color gray
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    } else {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    return view;
}
```

For more info please visit:-

[Add hint in spinner](https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-spinner-hint.html)