# how I can hide the element with index 0 from dropdown list in spinner

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Please tell me how can I hide the item at index 0 from the dropdown in the spinner in Android Studio? I am using this code, it works, but when I open the list, it shows at the bottom. That is, it is focused on the elements below. what do i need to change?

```
SpinnerName = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        names.add(0, "SELECT");
        names.add(1, "Name1");
        names.add(2, "Name2");
        

       final int listsize = names.size()-1;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names){
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return(listsize); 
            }
        };

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        SpinnerName.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_list);
        SpinnerName.setSelection(listsize);
       
       
        SpinnerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                                       long id) {

                ....

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a list of the correct elements?

Comment: @HenryTwist I need to display "Select.." sentence, if spinner is closed.

Comment: this is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019941/how-to-add-a-hint-in-spinner-in-xml and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508512/how-to-add-a-hint-in-spinner/49508686

Answer (score 0):

```
SpinnerName.setSelection(listsize);
```

> your problem is here! you are passing the total list size number and
> that where you are doing wrong, because setSelection method use to
> show default index of spinner.

you can simply do that `SpinnerName.setSelection(1);` that would give you the fist spinner item unless showing the `names.add(0, "SELECT");` item

Comment: It works, but I need to display this 0 item, if spinner is closed and hide, when open

Comment: SpinnerName.setSelection(0);  use that